# Generating a number between 1 and 2 java Math.random()

Tags: java, math, random

I'm working on creating a range of numbers between 1 and 2 using the imported math.random() class.

Here's how I got it working so far, however I can't see how it would work:

```
int tmp = (int)(Math.random()*1)+1;
```

Anyonould?e know if that actually works to get the range? if not.. then what

EDIT: Looking for either the number 1 or 2.

Comment: There are no integers between 1 and 2. So what are you trying to generate actually?

Answer (score 10):

If you want the values 1 or 2 with equal probability, then `int temp = (Math.random() <= 0.5) ? 1 : 2;` is all you need.  That gives you a 1 or a 2, each with probability 1/2.

Comment: Not really, you should do < 0.5 and not <= 0.5 for equal probability, right?

Comment: @peter.petrov Mathematically it's discrete inversion of the CDF, and CDF's are `<=` inequalities.  Computationally you could argue that the RNG yields 0 but not 1, so there's an asymmetry to the tune of one part in 2**31-1, which practically speaking makes no difference.  Since I'm a statistician by trade, I tend to go with a straight-up translation the mathematical definition.

Comment: @peter.petrov This also would lend itself easily to splitting the mix to a different proportion.  Simply change the proportion value in the test to a new target.

Comment: @peter.petrov I think you could argue that mathematically you have two equivalent ranges, while technically I don't.  Yours requires more computation by a hair (addition, floor, and casting vs a single comparison). I don't think any statistical test could tell the difference in the results based on any sample size people are actually likely to draw.

Comment: @pjs I think the asymmetry is more like one part in 2**52-1, not 2**31-1.  `Math.random` returns a `double` which has 52 significant bits of precision.

Comment: @ajb Thanks for the info. I think the bottom line is that nobody would be able to tell the difference whether you use a `<` or a `<=` on this one.

Answer (score 7):

```
int tmp = (int) ( Math.random() * 2 + 1); // will return either 1 or 2
```

`Math.random()` returns numbers from `[0, 1)`. Because `(int)` always rounds down (floors), you actually want the range `[1,3)`, so that `[1,2)` will be rounded to 1 and `[2,3)` will be rounded to 2.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
int tmp = (int)( Math.floor( Math.random() + 1.5 ) )
```

`Math.random() -> [0, 1)`

`Math.random() + 1.5 -> [1.5, 2.5)`

So when you take the floor, it is either 1 or 2 with equal 
probability because `[1.5, 2.5) = [1.5, 2) U [2, 2.5)` 
and `length([1.5, 2)) = length([2, 2.5)) = 0.5`.

Comment: +1, but you don't need the `Math.floor`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you want to use `Math.random`, but you could use `java.util.Random` so no casting or rounding is required:

```
    java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();
    int tmp = random.nextInt(2) + 1;
```

Comment: +1 I was looking at these answers and was wondering why no one was using `Random`. Especially since you can replace it with `SecureRandom`.

Comment: I'm using this code for a class, we're supposed to say in the curriculum and math.random() was the only random taught.

Comment: It is part of `java.util`, that class is there to solve this kind of problems.